# PHPUnit stub throws exception but isn't allowed to be caught

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm trying to test a try/catch block using a stub that throws an exception when a certain method `create` is called. It works fine, the exception is raised, but instead of my application catching it, it stops the execution of the test. What is some better ways to go about doing this.

```
<?php
// TestCase
        $mockDao->expects($this->once())
                ->method('create')
                ->will($this->throwException(new \Exception));

        $service->addEntity($data);
?>


<?php
// Service
    public function addEntity($data)
    {
           ....

        try {
               ...
            $this->create($entity); // Test Halts with Exception
               ...
        } catch (Exception $e) {
           // Never Gets Called
           $this->handleException($e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are throwing `\Exception` but catching `Exception`. Is the class that implements `addEntity()` in a namespace? Does changing it to catch `\Exception` fix the problem? If not, try changing the test to throw `Exception`.

Comment: Wow. Yeah you're absolutely right, thanks. I must have refactored and shuffled things around for 2 hours trying to see what was happening. I didn't even think about it.

Comment: Had the same problem because the code tested was namespaced and the Exception didn't have a backslash.